# Cannot fit Markov model in R

Tags: r, statistics, markov-chains, markov, operations-research

I am doing Markov process for my assignment using R. I already designed my matrix but the problem is I cannot put my matrix into markov object. The error is saying ..

> Error in validObject(.Object) :
>
> invalid class “markovchain” object:
>   1: Error! Row sums not equal to one check positions: 2
>
> invalid class“markovchain” object: 2: Error! Row sums not equal to one check
>   positions: 4
>
> invalid class “markovchain” object: 3: Error! Row sums
>   not equal to one check positions: 6
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In if (check == FALSE) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Here is my code

```
library(markovchain)
areaStates <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
areaMatrix <- matrix(data = c(0,0.2,0,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                              0.33,0,0.33,0.33,0,0,0,
                              0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                              0.33,0.33,0.33,0,0,0,0,
                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0.5,0,0,0,1,0,0.5,
                              0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0), byrow = T, nrow = 7,
                     dimnames = list(areaStates, areaStates))
area <- new("markovchain", states = areaStates, byrow = T,
                 transitionMatrix = areaMatrix, name = "Area")
```

Comment: So what about the 6th row of the matrix? It has probabilities 0.5, 0.5, 1, which are far from summing up to 1.

Comment: The error is pointing you to the rows causing the problem, try running `rowSums(areaMatrix)`